# Flask wtforms nested variables

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

i would like to use nested variables inside my wtforms as:
{{ render_field(form.date, size=32, class="form-control", value="**{{date}}**", disabled=true) }}

Of course {{date}} will be seen as a string and just displayed. How can i pass a second variable inside a variable?
Need to pass the actual date inside the Input field as a value.

Thanks in advance!

K3V1N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write it just like this: `..., value = date, ...`, you can put any varibles directly here as it's already in the `{{ }}` scope.